# Google Sheets formula - change format of data

Tags: datetime, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

How to add to this formula if value is 1/1/1970 replace with blank value?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(L2:L/86400000+DATE(1970,1,1))
```

I got data through API so I change format of data with this formula but I have values with 1/1/1970, I would like to have instead of these values only blank cells.

Comment: This looks like Google Sheets, not Excel. Edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(L2:L/86400000+DATE(1970; 1; 1)=DATE(1970; 1; 1);; 
 L2:L/86400000+DATE(1970; 1; 1)))
```